Disable inlay hints in DataGrip
Inlay hints in DataGrip misalign my SQL code. How can I turn this feature off?


You can disable the inlay hints in File | Settings | Editor | Inlay Hints
As for the misalignment issue, please report it on our tracker
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE
and include your SQL example to investigate this behavior.

As of DataGrip 2024.1.2, the only way I was able to find out how to do this was to:

Go into Settings
Search for "inlay"
Go to the Keymap (Other > Toggle Inlay Hints Globally)
Bind a hotkey
Run the hotkey


